# How to import a package on a specific branch with go modules

Tags: go

I'm reorganizing a repo from the following structure:

```
repo_root/
   |- foo/
       |- foo.go
   |- bar/
       |- bar.go
   |- go.mod
```

into the following:

```
repo_root/
   |- gosrc/
        |- foo/
             |- foo.go
        |- bar/
             |- bar.go
        |- go.mod
```

Now, inside `foo.go` of the original repo structure, I do something like below to import the package `bar`:

```
import "github.com/arb_name/repo_root/bar"
```

Now, with the new repo, I changed it to:

```
import "github.com/arb_name/repo_root/gosrc/bar"
```

Now, I run into the problem that `go build` of `foo.go` failed because

> cannot find module providing package github.com/arb_name/repo_root/gosrc/bar

I certainly do not want to change the master branch of repo without first making sure that the restructure of repo works. I'm wondering if there is a way to solve my situation? I can work on my fork but ideally not directly making change to my fork's master.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? The `import` statement doesn't set the version. The version you're attempting to use will be recorded in `go.mod`, and can be overridden with `replace`. If you're not using the correct version at all, fetch it with `go get`. See the documentation at: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you updated your **go.mod** file to

> module github.com/arb_name/repo_root/gosrc

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, it seems the same error is thrown.

Comment: @xxks-kkk could you please show how your go.mod file looks like

Comment: My `go.mod` is under `gosrc/` directory with the top line `module github.com/arb_name/repo_root/gosrc`

Comment: Thanks for help! I just realized some package import path still has the old path. Everything works now.